# karma cannot load files injected by requirejs

Tags: requirejs, karma-runner

I'm having troubles getting a simple karma test to run. I have the following code structure:

```
js/
  |-- tests.js
  |-- karma.config.js
  |-- app/
         |-- controllers.js
  |-- tests/
         |-- unit/
                 |-- loginSpec.js
  |-- vendor/
         |-- jquery.js
```

I'm following the documentation at http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/plus/RequireJS.html and have my configuration set up as follow (minus the unimportant parts):

```
// base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
basePath = '';

// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files = [
    JASMINE,
    JASMINE_ADAPTER,
    REQUIRE,
    REQUIRE_ADAPTER,
    'tests.js',
    {pattern: 'tests/unit/*.js', included: false}
];
```

In my controllers.js, I define a function called `LoginCtrl` and I want to test this function in `loginSpec.js`

```
define(['controllers'],function(controllers) {
    describe('Login controllers', function() {
        describe('LoginCtrl', function(){
            it('should return 1', function() {
                var scope = {},
                ctrl = new LoginCtrl(scope);
                expect(1).toBe(1);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

The problem is my browser cannot load the `controllers.js` file eventhough I've set up my main test file's requirejs configuration (`tests.js`) as follow:

```
var tests = Object.keys(window.__karma__.files).filter(function (file) {
      return /Spec\.js$/.test(file);
});
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: '/base/app',
    paths: {
        jquery: 'vendor/jquery',
    },
    deps: tests,
    callback: window.__karma__.start
});
```

The browser does look for a file at `http://localhost:9876/base/app/controllers.js`. Isn't this the right path?

Answer (score 1):

The path is not okay I think, it should be `jquery: '../vendor/jquery'`, because the requirejs base points to the `app` dir. But this is not the only problem...

By karma you should add every file to the patterns you want to use. The files with the flag `include: true` will be runned by karma, the others can be used by tests. If two patterns cover a file name then the first pattern will override the second (so this is in reverse order than we usually do). In your case you should use something like this as `karma.conf.js`:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: './',
        frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],
        files: [
            {pattern: 'tests.js', included: true},
            {pattern: 'test/**/*.js', included: false},
            {pattern: 'app/**/*.js', included: false},
            {pattern: 'vendor/**/*.js', included: false}
        ],
        exclude: [

        ],
        reporters: ['progress'],
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: true,
        browsers: ['Firefox'],
        captureTimeout: 6000,
        singleRun: false
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem, but I didn't find nice solution. I had to apply "hack" by adding .js extension to in my spec file, in your case try to change 'controllers' to 'controllers.js' in your loginSpec.js